# Django Autocomplete Light override html options to return custom value

Tags: django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I am starting to use DAL, but I cannot use the default behavior that set the  value to the PKs of the objects in my queryset.
So I overriden the 'get_result_value' function to set a custom field as the value of my options.

```
class CategoryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        country = Agent.get_user_country(self.request.user)
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Category.objects.none()
        qs = Category.objects.filter(country=country)
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(full_category__icontains=self.q)
        return qs

    def get_result_value(self, result):
        return result.special_key
```

My issue is that when I submit I get this ModelChoiceField error:

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

Here is the Form:

```
class OnsiteCategoryForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), required=True,
                                      widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='category_autocomplete'))
```

Do you have any idea of what could be causing this error ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is not meant to be a full answer but I'm exactly on your same search track and your Q put me in a "almost-working-direction".

By this I mean that I implemented the `get_result_value` as per your code and I can get the new value (which in my case is a `slug`) with JS in the template listening to the `select2:select` event.

```
$('select').on('select2:select', function (event) {
  console.log(event.params.data.id);
}
```

my views.py:

```
class DjProfileAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = DjProfile.objects.all()
        return qs.filter(name__icontains=self.q) if self.q else qs

    def get_result_value(self, result):
        return result.slug

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': HomeForm()})
```

my forms.py:

```
class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    dj_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=DjProfile.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
            url='dj-autocomplete',
            attrs={
                # Set some placeholder
                'data-placeholder': 'Trova Dj',
                # Only trigger autocompletion after 3 characters have been typed
                'data-minimum-input-length': 3,
            },
        )
    )
```

Note that in the above jQuery snippet I still refer to `id`, but now the `event.params.data.id` attribute contains the `slug` ...

Comment: Yes you refer to data.id because id here refers to the html tag's id.

Do you have the same error as me ?
"Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."